# Cannot read property of an undefined object in a IF statement in JEST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a simple if-else statement as

```
if(this.props.params.id){
    //do something
}
```

Now, this works fine in the browser.
If there is an id in the params it enters the if clause and doesn't if there is no id.

Now while writing test with jest, when the id is not defined it throws an error:
"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"
Why is this happening, shouldnt it treat it as false? 
It works fine in the browser, just in the testing it throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If id itself is undefined, then your test works as expected (although there are much better ways of writing it)

The problem you are getting is from this.props.params being undefined. In that case, you are trying to access a property of something that doesn't exist.

To solve for this, you need to check if both params AND id are defined.

You can do that like this:

```
if (typeof this.props.params !== 'undefined' && this.props.params.id !== 'undefined') {
    //do something
}
```

Its much better to use typeof for checking for undefined variables, as it is possible for your if statement to fail if the variable evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can check:

```js
if (bar.foo) {
// do something
}
```

You first have to check for:

```js
if (bar) {
  if (bar.foo) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Or in one statement...

```js
if (bar && bar.foo) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(this.props.params){
    var id = this.props.params.id;
}
```